# printing mysql ROW_COUNT() result from shell

Tags: mysql, shell, unix

Let's say i'm having a query that delete some data from the database, and returns at the end
the number of rows deleted using mysql SELECT ROW_COUNT().

```
delete from person where creation_date < DATE_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 4 HOUR);SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

this is my bash script

```
rows=$($MYSQL -h $MARIADB_HOST -P $MARIADB_PORT -u $MARIADB_USER --password=$MARIADB_PASSWORD -D $MARIADB_NAME -s -N < script.sql )
```

when i'm calling echo to print the result like this

```
echo $rows
```

it works and prints the nb of rows affected correctly.

However when i call it inside quotes, it dosn't work and it prints 
**" was deleted"**

```
echo "$rows was deleted"
```

i don't know what is happening ? for information i'm running the script in cygwin

Answer (score 0):

it seems that special characters are causing this issue.

```
nbRows=`echo $rows | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'`
```